# Sort array based on frequency

Tags: arrays, sorting

How can I sort an array by most repetitive values.?

```
suppose I have an array [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]

Expected the result as [3, 4] since 3 is most repeated and 4 is least repeated.
```

Is there any way too do it?

Thanks in advance....!

Comment: Are they in sorted order?

Comment: @Vishy : not sorted yet, it may also be [3,2,3,4,2,1,3]

Comment: What language? In Python you'd just do `[k for k,v in collections.Counter(arr).most_common()]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it:

`distictList`: Get all distinct values from the array and store in this

`countArray`: For each `i`th index in `distinctList` `countArray[i]` holds the occurrence of the `distinctList[i]`

Now sort `countArray` and apply same swaps on the `distinctList` simultaneously.

Ex: [3, 3, 4, 4, 4]

distinctList [3,4]

countArray [2,3]

Descending sort countArray [3,2] sorting distinctList at the same time [4,3]
Output: [4, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

Simple in Python:

```
data = [3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3]

frequencies = {x:0 for x in data}
for x in data:
    frequencies[x] = frequencies[x] + 1
sorted_with_repetitions = sorted(data, key=lambda x:frequencies[x],reverse=True)
sorted_without_repetitions = sorted(frequencies.keys(), key=lambda x:frequencies[x],reverse=True)

print(data)
print(sorted_with_repetitions)
print(sorted_without_repetitions)
print(frequencies)
```

The same approach (an associative container to collect distinct values and count occurrences, used in a custom comparison to sort an array with the original data or only distinct items) is suitable for Java.